# Sorting a product by price

Tags: php, mysql

Say I have a table of products with fields `regular_price` and `sale_price` and I want to sort these products by current price, how would you go about it?

A solution would be to check & update a new field `price` based on if `sale_price` had a value every time the product is loaded. But that feels really messy & I don't really want to have to duplicate data if I can help it.

Thanks!

EDIT: To add extra complexity I also need to be able to convert this php statement into the query:

```
if ( $this->sale_price_dates_from   <= $time && 
        $this->sale_price_dates_to >= $time &&
        $this->sale_price)
    return true;
```

EDIT2: `$time` refers to the current unix timestamp.

My table structure is:
`meta_id`, `post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`

All fields `sale_price`, `regular_price`..dates ect are stored in `meta_key` with the corresponding value in `meta_value`.

All dates are stored as unix timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ORDER BY IFNULL(sale_price, regular_price)`

**Edit:**
Your php statement to the query is like below:

```
WHERE (meta_key = 'sale_price_dates_from' AND meta_value <= NOW())
AND (meta_key = 'sale_price_dates_to' AND meta_value >= NOW())
AND (meta_key = 'sale_price' AND meta_value IS NOT NULL)
AND meta_id = ?
```

Comment: Sorry @xdazz thanks for your answer you caught me while editing my question. Any idea how you'd do the edit too?

Comment: @studioromeo That is just add some where condition, isn't that?

Comment: Hm, yes but the product doesn't always require dates to be on sale.

Comment: @studioromeo You should give the table structure and what does `$time` pointed to?